# Finding the single digits of a number

Tags: java, string, substring

In java, I want to check if each of the digits of a number are odd or even. For example, if you were to run the code through, you would get-

```
13451: 4 odd 1 even
5555 : 4 odd
18529: 3 odd 2 even
```

From what I would see, you could turn the number into a string, and the substring it into pieces. Then, after doing that, you could check if it is odd or not.

But how?

Code (and a little bit more of an explanation)

```
public class numberSorter
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0;i<100000;i++){
        //So here I want it so that I can see which numbers from 1-100000
        //have all odd number digits.Using a for loop makes it easier,
        //but how would you do it with "i"?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing some code would be your best bet

Comment: @Reimeus For the question or for the answer...?

Comment: You want to put your "oddness-checker" into a method and call it from inside the loop: `for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) { checkForOdd(i); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are curious just for the numbers which has only odd digits you do not absolutely need to count the numbers of odd and even digits. If you need to resolve this problem by counting them the correct answer will be that numbers which has 0 even digits. For that you can see many answers in this topic. If not, I suggest you to use this simple function in your loop:

```
//This function checks if a specific number has only odd digits
private static boolean isHasAllDigitsOdd(int number)
{
    //first of all check if the number is 0
    if(number==0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //while the last digit is odd cut that form the number
    while((number>0)&&(number%2==1))
    {
        number /= 10;
    }

    //if the number is 0 then all of its digits were cut
    if(number ==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else//otherwise it has a even digit
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So after defining the function, your loop will look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 0;i<100000;i++){
        if(isHasAllDigitsOdd(i))
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testEvenOdd(){
    for(int i = 0;i<100000;i++){
        int even = 0; 
        int odd  = 0; 

        String number = Integer.toString(i);
        for (int index = 0; index < number.length();index++){
            int num = number.charAt(index); 
            if (even(num)){
                even++;
            }
            else{
                odd++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i+" " + even + " even " + odd + " odd");
        }
}

public boolean even(int number){
    if (number%2==0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. Here is one using a while loop:

```
int startingNum = num;
int evenCount = num == 0 ? 1 : 0; // handles the 0 input
int oddCount = 0;
while (num > 0) {
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        evenCount++;
    else
        oddCount++;
    num /= 10;
}
System.out.println(startingNum + " : " + oddCount + " odd " + evenCount + " even");
```

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. But what about using a for loop as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long number = 12354689;
    long dividor = (long) Math.pow(10,String.valueOf(number).length()-1);
    int oddNum = 0;
    int evenNum = 0;

    while(dividor >= 1){
        if(((int) number/dividor) % 2 == 0)
            evenNum = evenNum + 1;
        else
            oddNum = oddNum + 1;
        dividor = dividor/10;
    }
    System.out.println("Even Number = " + evenNum);
    System.out.println("Odd Number = " + oddNum);


}
```